# OnMainThreadException When Trying to Upload Data from Android to PHP

Tags: android

Can Someone tell me how can i fix the problem below?

I have this piece of code, and i'm trying to Upload some data into PHP.

If i try to run it from the MainThread my app crashes.

I also tried to use AsyncTask or Runnable tread but i still get the same error.

How can i run this code properly to fix there errors.
[image]

```
ArrayList<String> offlineData = new ArrayList<String>();
UploadingClass upClass = new UploadingClass(context);
DatabaseAdapter helper = new DatabaseAdapter(context);

offlineData = helper.getAllOfflineData();

        for(int i=0;i<offlineData.size();i++)
        {
         upClass.uploadUnRegisteredData(helper.getUserId().toString(), offlineData.get(i).toString());          
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `Toast` to the main application thread, such as in `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: LoL... thx.. i had a Toast in my uploadUnRegisteredData() method. Fixed!